# Scikit Learn Multilabel Classification, Getting back labels from MultiLabelBinarizer

Tags: scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

In a multilabel classification problem, i use MultiLabelBinarizer to transform my 20 text labels into a binary list of zeros and ones.

After prediction I get my list of 20 binary values, and I would like to output the corresponding text labels.

I am just wondering whether MultiLabelBinarizer() provides a getting back transformation or I should do it manually.

Comment: By the way, MultiLabelBinarizer().classes_ stores the order of labels in the conversion list. So a for loop to print indices in MultiLabelBinarizer().classes_ corresponding to the ones in my prediction is enough, though annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, The MultiLabelBinarizer provides a method named `inverse_transform()` which will convert the binarized labels back to the original names that were supplied to it during `fit()`.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.inverse_transform

> inverse_transform(yt)
>
> ```
> Transform the given indicator matrix into label sets
> Parameters:   
>
> yt : array or sparse matrix of shape (n_samples, n_classes)
>
>     A matrix containing only 1s ands 0s.
>
> Returns:  
>
> y : list of tuples
>
>     The set of labels for each sample such that y[i] consists of classes_[j] for each yt[i, j] == 1.
> ```

Comment: Great. It works. To sum up: 1)`mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()`
2) `y = mlb.fit_transform(labels)` 3) `print mlb.inverse_transform(clf.predict(test[0]))`

Comment: Yes. Thats Correct

Comment: How to `inverse_transform()` when instead of `predict()`, we use `predict_proba()`?

Comment: @loving_guy `inverse_transform()` may only be used for original values (targets). If you used `predict_proba`, then you first need to decide the threshold for which you want a particular target class to be assigned for that sample. Once that is done for all values, then use `inverse_transform()`